# Enviar datos en el body por Post en Axios

Tags: nodejs, express, axios

quiero saber como leer los campos del body y enviarlos por POST con axios en NodeJs.
Mi error dice que **name Unused label**.

```
axios.post('/usuario',(req,res) => {
  name : req.body.name
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas que el método [`post`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) de `axios` recibe una función `callback` con objetos `request` y `response`?

Comment: @MauricioContreras es que queria uar el req,body de express por eso lo use, se que esta mal la sintaxis pero en el ejemplo que esta en la documentacion en el post siempre le manda los mismos valores hardcodeados y yo queria ver como enviarles unos parametros que el usuario envie por el body con axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que tienes una confusión de conceptos, entre lo que se recibe en una petición a un servidor NodeJS con [Express](https://expressjs.com/) y el uso de [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) para solicitudes `http` desde NodeJS.

Según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, deseas realizar una petición con `axios` usando un valor recibido en el objeto `body` de una solicitud a Express.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma en la que puedes realizar la tarea sería escribir la solicitud `post` de `axios` dentro de la función *middleware* que maneja la petición a una ruta de Express.

Supongamos que tienes la siguiente ruta y su función *middleware*:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// configuramos express
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true});

// escribimos el middleware que maneja la ruta
// usualmente se usa un método post para manejar datos enviados
// en el cuerpo (body) de la solicitud
app.post("/laruta", (req, res) => {
  // manejo de la ruta
  let name = req.body.name;
  // ...
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Servidor escuchando");
});
```

Dentro de esta función *middleware* podemos usar `axios` para realizar una petición `http` a cualquier otro servicio **externo** a nuestra aplicación. Lo que hacemos es construir el cuerpo de la solictud `axios` tal como se muestra en la [documentación](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases):

```js
// ...
const axios = require("axios");


app.post("/laruta", (req, res) => {
  // manejo de la ruta
  let name = req.body.name;
  axios.post(urlExterna, {name: name})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // ... hacemos otras cosas
    return res.status(200).json({
      response: response
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // manejamos el error
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Upps, algo fue mal"
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Servidor escuchando");
});
```

Esta sería una forma muy básica de usar `axios` en un proyecto Express con NodeJS.

Toma en cuenta que la solicitud se hace a una `url` externa. Si deseas hacerla a una ruta de tu propio servidor Express, entonces no necesitas `axios` para nada. Basta con concatenar los *middleware* de forma adecuada.

Comment: Mauricio disculpa podrias ayudarme con pregunta que publique por favor